# What is stopping anyone from going around and up/down-voting anything and everything?

Tags: discussion, voting, rate-limiting

So what is stopping me from up or down voting anything and everything on Stack Overflow?

More importantly, what is stopping anyone from going around an up or down voting anything and everything?

Comment: You have a limited number of votes per day. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @RobertLongson, what is the limit?

Comment: Your conscience.

Comment: @Tunaki, So I could potentially be a troll , create a few accounts and start down voting what ever I come across?

Comment: Yeah. But you'll be noticed quite rapidly and _taken care of_.

Comment: Well no you cannot. "Awarded At: 15 Reputation"

Comment: @RadLexus, how is so?

Comment: @RadLexus, does not take much to earn 15 rep

Comment: Still, it's a barrier to your plan of Taking Over The World (Ha! Ha! Ha!) by continuously creating new accounts and downvoting everything and eveyone. It's small but real.

Comment: You need 125 rep to downvote

Comment: @RadLexus, No , I am concerned the site is being abused.

Comment: Ah right. 15 to vote up, [125 to vote down](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: lol 'I am concerned the site is being abused', sounds like the inevitable 'for learning and research purposes only' disclaimer that appears on every 'help me write malware' SO post.

Comment: The site *is* being abused. Just about every clear homework assignment seems to get an upvote - most likely as in "yeah it'd be *really* useful for everybody  if someone wrote that code for me as well". But if you suspect something iffy is going on with up or downvotes in a certain tag, you may have caught a **voting ring**. You can flag such posts and report them to SO for further investigation.

Answer (score 12):

There are three main things:

- You can only vote 30 times a day (+10 Questions only)
- Excessive voting for specific users is subject to removal by the serial voting reversal script (that runs daily)
- Locked posts cannot be voted on

Other then these, nothing.

Please note that making extra accounts just to vote more is considered abuse and will lead to suspension / deletion of the extra accounts.

Please further note that upvoting has a reputation requirement (15) and downvoting has a reputation requirement (125) and that downvotes on Answers cost you 1 reputation each.

Comment: How does SO know this?

Comment: The exact means of finding out are not disclosed to not make it easy to game them, but they have sophisticated algorhitms that detect voting tomfoolery. And user reports, ofcourse.

Comment: I hope they work good, b/c there seems to be a lot inconstancy in up and down votes.

Comment: @Sanzōhōshi Is there a particular question you have an issue with? Because I don't agree with that statement, at all.

Comment: @Sanzōhōshi examples?

Comment: The main inconsistency with votes, IMO, is that there are generally way too few downvotes.

Comment: @Pekka웃 well, having spent ages setting up 20 puppets and carefully organizing your global voting ring, it seems conterproductive to downvote anything at all.

Comment: @MartinJames Why else would you spend the effort setting up such a voting ring other than to cast downvotes?

Answer (score 6):

From the [vote privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

> You can vote 30 times per UTC day, plus 10 more times on questions only.

Since there are more than 40 questions per day on Stack Overflow it's not possible to vote on everything even if you use the site every day.

Comment: What if I made several accounts?

Comment: The moderators would close them and ban you. You're not allowed to do anything with multiple accounts that you couldn't do if you only had one account.

Comment: Using VPN would allow anonymity, no?

Comment: @Sanzōhōshi SO has very sophisticated tools to try and detect this.  You may get away with it but you may not.

Comment: People doing that are regularly caught so I assume that moderators have tools which will catch people even if they use a VPN.